# SceneKit generate pipe along path

Tags: ios, scenekit, scngeometry

I'm currently trying to find out how to generate a pipeline 3D object from given points `P` (Array of n `SCNVector3`) and radius `r`, where `P[i]` is the center of the cylinder. I can't simply generate `n-1` [SCNCylinder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncylinder)s and place them between `P[i-1]` and `P[i]`, because the connection between the cylinders would look ugly.

I've seen, that you can generate a custom geometry using a [SCNGeometrySource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometrysource). But as far as I understand, I'd have to calculate the surfaces and their normals and their connections manually.

This answer for blender describes what I want to achieve (but with a array of `SCNVector3` instead of a bezier curve.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8686

Here is a different video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_ciyeTmZx4

**My question is:**

Is there something built in that provides this functionality or do I really have to calculate everything manually? I'm not that much into SceneKit right now, and might just miss the correct search term for this feature. Any suggestions?

Comment: P contains the center of the cylinder and what other point?

Comment: What you require is an SCNTube geometry I suppose. But I'm a little confused on what P is, how many elements it has, etc.

Comment: @SWAT I updated the question. P is an array of n `SCNVector3`